# Entering formula in excel using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have searched a lot on this forum and on net but couldn't find solution for my answer.

I need to enter formulas in excel using visual studio (2013) form that I have created. I have entered the required commands but it shows me the wrong row.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\14.xlsx")
    'xlApp.Visible = True
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'xlWorkSheet.Unprotect()
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 5 'have lots of headers so finally empty row starts on 5th
    With xlWorkSheet
        Do While .Cells(iRow, 2).value <> ""
            .Cells(iRow, 2).activate()
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop
        .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = t1.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = t2.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = t4.Text

        .Cells(iRow, "AB").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[" & iRow & "]C22<R[" & iRow & "]C27,""Yes"",""No"")"

    End With
```

It enters in the correct row (irow value) but in the formula instead of showing V5'<'AA5 (5 being incremented with each insertion) it is showing V10'<'AA10. Why?
I tried to define an integer variable and then divide iRow value with 2 but still it's not working properly.

Please help!

Comment: Why do you have `.Cells(iRow,2).Activate`? That doesn't do anything in your routine, but I think you're expecting it to do something?

Comment: Ya it doesn't do anything. I deleted that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The problem was of relative addressing. So, instead of using iRow in the formula I used a variable which I set to 0